# How to enable dependencies with python?

Tags: python, dependencies, smartsheet-api

I've written a python program to define and load a sheet in smartsheet from an Excel spreadsheet, and have provided a start date, end date, predecessors, duration and %complete columns in the definition (it works well).  But, now I want enable dependencies for the sheet using API 2.0 and tell smartsheet to use my predefined columns when enabling dependencies, just like I am able to do using the smartsheet GUI interface for the sheet.  I could not find a method in the API 2.0 documentation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not currently possible to create a dependency-enabled project sheet by using the Smartsheet API.  The information in the [Column Types](http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#column-types) section of the API documentation supports this assertion -- i.e., the *Duration*, *Predecessor*, *Start Date*, and *End Date* columns in a dependency-enabled project sheet are actually special column types -- but the API does not support creating columns of these types.

[image]

So currently, the only way to enable dependencies for a sheet and designate columns for *Duration*, *Predecessor*, *Start Date*, and *End Date* is to use the Smartsheet (web) UI.

Comment: Happy to help, sorry there isn't a way to accomplish what you're wanting to do.  Can you please mark this answer as an "accepted answer" (so that others will see that it's been answered correctly and may benefit from the info in the future)?